# List of "Always wrong" snippets in C

Tags: c

Was talking to a colleague today on one-spot errors - I.e. errors (or at least patterns that should ring an alarm bell) in code that a decent programmer should be able to spot at a single glance like

```
x = malloc (strlen(y));

while (!feof (f)) {
   ...
}

char *f(){
   char x[100];
   ...
   return x;
}
```

Who has similar snippets of such patterns? I would suggest anyone who has been on SO for a while will have his personal favourites of those

Comment: `void foo(T array[]){sizeof(array)}`

Comment: I think your question is interesting but not for SO. Maybe for programmers.stackexchange.com

Comment: What's wrong with the first one?

Comment: 'recv(anything);' - ignoring the return values from system calls.

Comment: I suggest to check list of bugs detected by any static code analyzer

Comment: `x = malloc(strlen(y+1));`

Comment: `double d = i / j` where i and j are ints

Comment: On Stack Overflow, `scanf`.

Comment: I'm the first one to mention this?  `void main()`

Comment: @EugeneSh. - doesn't allocate space for the string terminator (assuming it's allocating space to store a copy of `y`).

Comment: Any strxxx() call in server/client network code.

Comment: 'void addToLinkedList(list *aList, node *newNode);'

Comment: 'return pointerToLocalString;'

Comment: @EdPlunkett also: in production code, `scanf`

Comment: @M.M I didn't know there WAS such a thing as `scanf` in production code! That's not just an ominous sign; that's *get out of the building NOW!*

Comment: @stackptr Amongst others: Ask for a number and enter a character string  Then see what happens.

Answer (score 2):

```
char *buf;
scanf("%s", buf);
```

This is wrong, because no memory has been allocated for `buf`.

```
char buf[100];
scanf("%s", &buf);
```

This is wrong, because `scanf` expects a `char *`, not a `char (*)[n]`.

```
char c;
while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
    putchar(c);
```

This is wrong, because `EOF` does not fit in the range of a `char`. Use `int` instead.

```
fflush(stdin);
```

`fflush` is undefined for input streams, like `stdin`, albeit this is implemented as an extension in some compilers, like Microsoft C.

```
#define IN 0;
```

Do not put semicolons at the end of a `#define`.

```
blk = realloc(blk, n);
```

If `realloc` fails, any contents in `blk` will be lost, because `realloc` will return NULL. To solve the problem, copy the return value into a temporary and only if the temporary is not NULL, copy to the final destination.

Comment: Another one: after `T array[n];` expecting `&array` to be a `T**`.

Comment: Downvote explanation?

Comment: Your second example makes the very mistake I just commented on.

Comment: @EOF Arrays decay to pointers when passed to functions

Comment: But you're not passing the array to the function, you're passing *the address*  of the array to the function.

Comment: So what is the type then? @EOF pointer to array?

Comment: After `T array[n];`, the type of `&array` is `T(*)[n]`. How is that surprising?

Comment: fixed the error @EOF

Comment: Now, if you wanted to learn something, you'd read C11 draft standard n1570, *6.3 Conversions, 6.3.2.1 Lvalues, arrays, and function designators 3 Except when it is the operand of the sizeof operator, the _Alignof operator, or the unary & operator, or is a string literal used to initialize an array, an expression that has type ‘‘array of type’’ is converted to an expression with type ‘‘pointer to type’’ that points to the initial element of the array object and is not an lvalue.[...]* and be enlightened.

Comment: maybe mention that `scanf("%s", buf);` is also wrong in the second case